# Spring mongodb criteria

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I m using Spring Data with Mongodb and I m facing a problem. I cant execute my criteria query in my repository with this :

```
@Query("{'name':/.*?0.*/}")
 public List<DirectoryEntity> findByName(String name);
```

What is the good way of make it work ? I need simple criteria, the name contains param.

What is the good way to request with this annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **[`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)** operator in your query expression:

```
@Query("{'name':{'$regex':?0,$options:'i'}}")
public List<DirectoryEntity> findByName(String name);
```

The `i` option in the regex expression toggles case insensitivity, and allows all letters in the pattern to match upper and lower cases.